# How do I use Python to look at the values of one column in a dataframe and append a new value in another column based on those results?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a CSV file with one column full of values that resembles this...

| Column A |
| --- |
| Hi [First]! |
| Thank You! |
| What Car? |
| Are you [First] [Last]? |
| Did you know? |
| Save 25% [First]! |
| Get $2,000 Back! |
| Embrace the road ahead |
| Everyone saves 30%! |

What I would like to do is build some logic that goes through column A and then assigns a new value to column B based on what the logic found.

For example the end result would look like this...

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Hi [First]! | Personalized |
| Thank You! | Gratitude |
| What Car? | Curiosity |
| Are you [First] [Last]? | Personalized |
| Did you know? | Curiosity |
| Save 25% [First]! | Personalized |
| Get $2,000 Back! | Offer |
| Embrace the road ahead | Generic |
| Everyone saves 30% | Offer |

I'd like for the logic to find any instances where it matches column A before moving on to the next step as well. For example there's two values that have a percentage but one is personalized. I'd like to put the personalized at the top of hierarchy and then say anything else that has "save" or a percentage might be an offer.

The beginning of my code looks similarly to this. I know the logic is completely wrong, but I don't know what I need to do to fix it and get the results I'm looking for. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import re
import numpy as np

header_names=['Line', 'Type']
df = pd.read_csv('2021 Lines Types.csv',header=None, skiprows=1, names=header_names)

for i in df:
    if re.search('[First]|[Last]', df.columnA):
      columnB.append("Personalized")
    elif re.search('Save', df.columnA):
        columnB.append('Savings')
```

Comment: Use `np.where()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `np.select` for this case. It takes a list of conditions, and a list of the same length of replacement values. For each condition, all values that it matches will be replaced with the corresponding value. `np.select` also takes as a third parameter a default value when none of the conditions match.

```
conds = [
    df['Column A'].str.contains(r'\[(?:First|Last)\]'),
    df['Column A'].str.contains('Save'),
    df['Column A'].str.contains('?', regex=False),
    df['Column A'].str.contains('Thank', regex=False),
]

vals = [
    'Personalized',
    'Offer',
    'Curiosity',
    'Gratitude',
]

df['Column B'] = np.select(conds, vals, 'Generic')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  Column A      Column B
0              Hi [First]!  Personalized
1               Thank You!     Gratitude
2                What Car?     Curiosity
3  Are you [First] [Last]?  Personalized
4            Did you know?     Curiosity
5        Save 25% [First]!  Personalized
6         Get $2,000 Back!       Generic
7   Embrace the road ahead       Generic
8      Everyone saves 30%!       Generic
```